# apache nifi + get latest hdfs file with listhdfs

Tags: apache-nifi

I am trying to get a specific file ( latest file ) from a hdfs direcory using
listHDFS and fetchHDFS
the filenames are as following 
DATAFILE.D170412 where D Represents a date

I am trying to obtain functionality to only get the newest file and only get it once.

I have noticed that there is no file filter in listHDFS yet
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NIFI-3379 
so i am not sure how i should build this flow

My current flow is as following:
listHDFS -> list all my files in the source directory 
FetchHFDS -> trying to only fetch the file that i want to get with 
following property

HDFS Filename:

```
${path}/${filename}.D${time -1:format("yyMMdd")}
```

In order to get the file with yesterdays date in filename extension

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple solutions  possible here:

One of which I think of is:

1) Nifi has "Execute stream command" processor in which you can run your shell script to get the name of your latest file. The op can be written in an attribute.

2) Direct the op to FetchHDFS processor where file name would the name of the file obtained from step 1

PS: Use log attribute processor to understand more about attributes and  see what values have been set